# How do I set a minimum upper bound for an axis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set a minimum upper bound, specifically:

- The Y axis should start at 0
- The Y axis should go to at least 10, or higher (automatically scale)
- The upper bound for the Y axis should never be less than 10.

Seems like something Highcharts does, but I can't seem to figure out how. Anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't seem to have an option for doing this at chart creation time. However, they do expose a couple methods to interrogate the extremes and change the extremes, `getExtremes()` and `setExtremes(Number min, Number max, [Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation])` found in their [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#axis-object).

So, a possible solution (after chart creation):

```
if (chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax < 10) {
   chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 10);
}
```

`yAxis[0]` references the first y-axis, and I'm assuming that you only have one axis in this case. The [doc](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#axis-object) explains how to access other axes.

This isn't ideal, because the chart has to redraw which isn't too noticeable, but it's still there. Hopefully, Highcharts could get this sort of functionality built in to the options.

Comment: You can avoid the redrawing flicker by setting the at the chart's `load` event: `new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(event) {if (this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax < 10) {
   this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 10);
} } }, ... }, ...});`

Comment: Too bad there isn't a way to do this more cleanly. Perhaps I'll fork the repo and fix it if I get a few minutes.

Comment: see Ondkloss's answer

Answer (score 10):

A way to do this only using options (no events or functions) is:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minRange: 10,
    maxPadding: 0
}
```

Here `minRange` defines the minimum span of the axis. `maxPadding` defaults to 0.01 which would make the axis longer than 10, so we set it to zero instead.

This yields the same results as a `setExtreme` would give. See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/x459druv/).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [Julian D's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202186/how-do-i-set-a-minimum-upper-bound-for-an-axis-in-highcharts#comment11583553_9202631), the following avoids a potential re-positioning problem if your calculated max varies in number of digits to your desired upper bound.

In my case I had percentage data currently going into the 20's but I wanted a range of 0 to at least 100, with the possibility to go over 100 if required, so the following sets min & max in the code, then if dataMax turns out to be higher, reassigns max up to it's value. This means the graph positioning is always calculated with enough room for 3-digit values, rather than calculated for 2-digits then broken by squeezing "100" in, but allows up to "999" before there would next be a problem.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                thisSetMax = this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
                thisDataMax = this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax;
                if (thisDataMax > thisSetMax) {
                    this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, thisDataMax);
                    alert('Resizing Max from ' + thisSetMax + ' to ' + thisDataMax);
                }
            }
        }        
    },
    title: {
        text: 'My Graph'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan 2013', 'Feb 2013', 'Mar 2013', 'Apr 2013', 'May 2013', 'Jun 2013']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: '% Due Tasks Done'
        }
    }
    //Etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HigtCharts has a really good documentation of all methods with examples.

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--min

In your case I think you should the "min" and "max" properties of "yAxis".

> min : Number
>   The minimum value of the axis. If null the min value is automatically calculated. If the startOnTick option is true, the min value might be rounded down. Defaults to null.
>
> max : Number
>   The maximum value of the axis. If null, the max value is automatically calculated. If the endOnTick option is true, the max value might be rounded up. The actual maximum value is also influenced by chart.alignTicks. Defaults to null.

If you are creating your chart dynamically you should set

min=0
max=10 , if your all data values are less then 10

and

only min=0, if you have value greater then 10

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the minimum value of the axis and the interval of the tick marks in axis units like so:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        tickInterval: 10
    }
});
```

Also don't forget to set the max value.

Hope that helps.