# How change Highchart minimum value

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

For my highchart, I want to set maximum value of `100` and minimum value of `1`.

When I try to code like this, it outputs is `0-100` not `1-100`.

If I change or remove `max range`, it works fine for small values of `y`.

```
yAxis: {
            min:1,
            max:100,
            reversed: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Rank'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
},
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a minimum upper bound for an axis in Highcharts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202186/how-do-i-set-a-minimum-upper-bound-for-an-axis-in-highcharts)

Comment: i want y-axis label 1,25,50,75,100 , not 0,25,50,75,100. setExtremes not working form me. tnx for your replay

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(1,100);
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

If it is dynamic data/tick data you can set

```
startOnTick : false
```

This problem is discussed here also http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6862

Comment: i want y-axis label 1,25,50,75,100 , not 0,25,50,75,100. setExtremes not working form me. tnx for your replay

Comment: can you create jsfiddle of you highchart?

Comment: you can do something like this using labels formatter function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189921/how-to-set-a-static-minimum-value-for-axes-in-highcharts

Comment: for this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189921/how-to-set-a-static-minimum-value-for-axes-in-highcharts .    it dispaly line parallel to x-axis for every y value (1,2,3). 100 line parallel to x-axis, how can remove this line?

Comment: it is governed by tickInterval, it is set to 1 in that example.

Comment: yah, once `tickInterval: 1` removed, it not showing y axis label

Comment: Check this, but its just a hack not a solution http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/5Lb2v/12/. In your case the tickInterval is quite big so highchart optimized that layout. You can ask in highchart mailing list

Answer (score 3):

You can force the y-axis to have specific tick intervals using the tickPositioner function in the y-axis e.g.

```
        tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [1, 25, 50, 75, 100];
            return positions;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cU2md/

Comment: It's good for static data but if you are adding dynamic data then this is not the optimal solutions.. But it is good for this case so deserve a vote up :)

Comment: In tickPositioner you can calculate ticks dynamically, because you have acess to min/max value.

Comment: @Raunak Kathuria - if you have dynamic data, you can also dynamically create the values needed for the tickPositioner...